# Entity Framework 6 -> Use one property for two composite foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Background: We are receiving data from an external system that we are going to store in our database and the models are based on the information we are getting from them.

Everything has run smoothly except for one model that uses one property as a composite foreign key for **two different relationships**.

The code below will generate the error `Duplicate 'ForeignKey' attribute`. If I remove one of the `ForeignKey` attributes from `BusinessSystemId` I will instead get the error `The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.` I think the code clearly shows what I wan't to achieve however. That is ti use `BusinessSystemId` as two separate foreign keys in `TPCaseName`.

```
public class TPCase
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPCaseName> CaseNames { get; set; }
}

public class TPCaseName
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    [ForeignKey("TPName")]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CaseNames")]
    public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("TPName")]
    public int NameNo { get; set; }

    public virtual TPName TPName { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("TPNameType")]
    public string NameType { get; set; }

    public virtual TPNameType TPNameType { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}

public class TPName
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int NameNo { get; set; }

    public string NameCode { get; set; }
}
```

I could solve it by adding the following property to `TPCaseName` but it seems unnecessary since the information is already present in `BusinessSystemId`.

```
[ForeignKey("TPName"), Column(Order = x)]
public string BusinessSystemId2 { get; set; }
```

I have tried to search for questions with the same scenario but not found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to annotate the Navigation Property to specify the compound foreign key.  EG

```
        public class TPCase
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public int CaseId { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<TPCaseName> CaseNames { get; set; }
        }

        public class TPCaseName
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public int CaseId { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
            public int NameNo { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
            public string NameType { get; set; }


            [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,CaseId")]
            public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,NameNo")]
            public virtual TPName TPName { get; set; }

            //[ForeignKey("NameType")]
            // public virtual TPNameType TPNameType { get; set; }
            public string ContactName { get; set; }
        }

        public class TPName
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public int NameNo { get; set; }

            public string NameCode { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: @DaDavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you! I had no idea you could use comma separation for foreign keys.